# connect to a sybase database using visual studio 2003 and the .NET Framework 1.1

Tags: visual-studio, sap-ase, .net-framework-version

I'm developing an interface between my application (built with Visual Studio 2003 and the .NET Framework 1.1) and a Sybase database. I installed the Adaptive Server to store the database. The problem arises when I tried to reference the neeeded dll to my project, I have two dll's (Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient.dll and Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll) that can't be added, and searching the web I see there is a dll called "Sybase.Data.AseClient.dll" but don´t know where to get it from. Help!!

Answer (score 0):

It depends which version of Sybase do you have.
The drivers can be installed along with Sybase client installation.

You should have to dll files:

1. sybdrvadoXX.dll (where XX is a number)
2. Sybase.Data.AseClient or Sybase.AdoNet2.AseClient

The first one just throw in the bin directory.
The second one add to the references.

Good luck :)